# Is it safe to store documents under public_html if htaccess doesn't allow browsing folders?

Tags: php, .htaccess, security, document

I understand it's commonly suggested that documents such as user uploaded files be stored below the web root. However if the documents are stored in a folder in public_html and htaccess is setup to block the browsing of folders and the filename of the uploaded file is say a long randomly generated string, how would someone be able to access this file without permission anyway?

Comment: Are you linking to them from any page that is public? Brute force is a thing too.

Comment: They're linked to only on pages which are accessible to logged in users

Comment: If you want to absolutely ensure that only logged-in users can access those files, you need to do a permission check for any request for those files too. Otherwise you merely have a situation in which those files *probably* won't easily be discovered, but absolutely no guarantee for that.

Comment: The only problem with that is that I use Google Docs to preview certain documents embedded on certain pages and Google Docs needs some kind of public url to the doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if the web server doesn't allow public access by configuration, then nobody can access the files. However, not allowing access by configuration is more brittle than the files simply not being there at all. It can always happen that a careless admin misconfigures the server and suddenly allows access to those files, which is simply a non-issue if you keep the files out of the webroot to begin with. Perhaps you also have a secondary vulnerability in which somebody may be able to alter your .htaccess files, thereby allowing themselves in through the backdoor. Again, not an issue if the files simply aren't there at all.